# how to change to next page when clicked on button

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml

hi guys I'm new in qml programming and i was just wondering how can i switch to an other page when the user clicks on my button.  by the way how can i make a new page in the ubuntu sdk so that when the user clicks on the button goes to there.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is heavily inspired by the one provided by the official SDK [documentation](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-14.04/Ubuntu.Components.PageStack/). I only changed the default control to be Button instead of ListItem:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1

MainView {
    width: units.gu(48)
    height: units.gu(60)
    PageStack {
        id: pageStack
        Component.onCompleted: push(page0)
        Page {
            id: page0
            title: i18n.tr("Root page")
            visible: false
            Column {
                anchors.margins: units.gu(3)
                spacing: units.gu(3)
                anchors.fill: parent
                Button {
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                    text: i18n.tr("Page one")
                    onClicked: pageStack.push(page1, {color: UbuntuColors.orange})
                }
                Button {
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                    text: i18n.tr("External page")
                    onClicked: pageStack.push(Qt.resolvedUrl("MyCustomPage.qml"))
                }
            }
        }
        Page {
            title: "Rectangle"
            id: page1
            visible: false
            property alias color: rectangle.color
            Rectangle {
                id: rectangle
                anchors {
                    fill: parent
                    margins: units.gu(5)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To switch or create a new page, you just need to call the push method. The pushed page may be an Item, Component or URL.

Comment: its more like a new like, like when you click on a link in a web page you go to a new page in that same site, thats what i wanted to do

Comment: it's more like i have a page and there is a button saying "welcome enter the app" and when clicked on the button you enter a new page with a few other button that will redirect you to several other pages.